# What reasons are there to pass an argument to an initializer in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, init

What reasons are there to pass an argument to an initializer in objective C? I can't find the information.

Answer (score 2):

1. When a class operates on (and thus requires) an external object. An example of this is `NSScanner`, which iterates through substrings in an `NSString`.
2. When a class can be instantiated using already known information. An example of this is `-[NSArray initWithArray:]`, which copies the contents of another array.

Comment: Wanna set it as the correct answer then?